# How do I get a object/objects from CheckboxTreeViewer?

Tags: java, eclipse

I'm trying to obtain an object or objects from my `CheckboxTreeViewer`.

I set the content provider to supply the data, and I can get the data easily from a selected item. I would think it would be something like:
`treeViewer.getElements();`

But this works to get selected objects:

```
IStructuredSelection ss = (IStructuredSelection) treeViewer.getSelection();
if (ss.size() == 1) {  
  Object selectedObject = ss.getFirstElement();

   if (selectedObject instanceof IndividualNode) {
     individual = ((IndividualNode) selectedObject).getIndividual();                  
   }
}
```

that gives me my object I want from the selection.

Know how to get an object from the `treeViewer` if it's not selected?

There are methods like

```
treeViewer.getCheckedElements();
```

which returns Object[].

But can’t find anything like

```
treeViewer.getElements();
```

Much thanks,

Brandon

Answer (score 3):

Figured it out.

Access the Tree Items by using:

```
TreeItems[] treeItems = treeViewer.getTree().getItems();
```

then get the object by using getData()

```
for(int i = 0; i < treeItems.length; i++){
    Object itemObject = treeItems[i].getData();

    //Then cast to the object type       
    Foo foo = (Foo) itemObject;
}
```

This works for TreeViewer and CheckboxTreeViewer.

Comment: You canset this as the answer. 
Thanks for that! :)

Answer (score 0):

I don't think there is anything like this. The closest thing is the elementMap field in the StructureViewer, but this is private, so you really can't even make your own subclass and get this information.